# Checking the number of `ENTRY` by `EMPLOYEE` and if `ACTIVITY` was same in last 3 `ENTRY`ies

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I want to run a query where I want to find the total number of `TICKETS` same `EMPLOYEE` logged at least 3 `ENTRY` but there was no progress on the `TICKET`.
Unfortunately I am having problems on:

- How to check the progress on `TICKET`

`ENTRY` has `ACTIVITY_ID` and defined Activities are

```
INSERT INTO ACTIVITY(ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_NAME) VALUES ('RGSTR','REGISTER')
INSERT INTO ACTIVITY(ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_NAME) VALUES ('ASST','ASSISTANCE')
INSERT INTO ACTIVITY(ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_NAME) VALUES ('ADVTS','ADVERTISEMENT')
INSERT INTO ACTIVITY(ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_NAME) VALUES ('SALE','SALE')
INSERT INTO ACTIVITY(ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_NAME) VALUES ('RFND','REFUND')
INSERT INTO ACTIVITY(ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_NAME) VALUES ('EXTND','EXTEND')
```

so far what I did is:

```
SELECT
  TICKET.TICKET_ID,
  EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME,
  COUNT(TICKET.TICKET_ID) AS NUMBER
FROM ENTRY
JOIN EMPLOYEE ON ENTRY.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
JOIN TICKET ON ENTRY.TICKET_ID = TICKET.TICKET_ID
GROUP BY TICKET.TICKET_ID, EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID) >= 3
```

I selected some columns to see what will be the output(experimenting and trying to understand at this point when I have `SELECT COUNT(*)` output is two rows and both is 3. this is counting the `ENTRY` for each ticket but I want to count the `TICKET`s that have >= 3 `ENTRY` and additional property mentioned above )

```
ID  LAST_NAME   NUMBER  No Column Name
5   LaBeouf      3        3
6   Musk         3        3
```

this output is not wrong since I have in `ENTRY` table like below but I basically want to get number of rows in this output and couldn't do it.

```
--more entries above
--.
--.
INSERT INTO ENTRY(ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,TICKET_ID,DATE,DESCRIPTION)
VALUES ('RGSTR',6,5,'2020-5-29','Didnt do anything')
INSERT INTO ENTRY(ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,TICKET_ID,DATE,DESCRIPTION)
VALUES ('RGSTR',6,5,'2020-5-29','Didnt do anything')
INSERT INTO ENTRY(ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,TICKET_ID,DATE,DESCRIPTION)
VALUES ('RGSTR',6,5,'2020-5-29','Didnt do anything')

INSERT INTO ENTRY(ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,TICKET_ID,DATE,DESCRIPTION)
VALUES ('RGSTR',2,6,'2020-5-29','Didnt do anything')
INSERT INTO ENTRY(ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,TICKET_ID,DATE,DESCRIPTION)
VALUES ('RGSTR',2,6,'2020-5-29','Didnt do anything')
INSERT INTO ENTRY(ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,TICKET_ID,DATE,DESCRIPTION)
VALUES ('RGSTR',2,6,'2020-5-29','Didnt do anything')
```

lastly I designed the database myself as part of the project here is the [ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zFKO.png) if it is going to help you understand better.

Thanks anyone who take their time to help

Edit: Resolved, I basically counted the rows in output above and added a Where statement that it will count only `ENTRY`ies with `ACTIVITY_ID='RGSTR'`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS # FROM 
(SELECT 
      TICKET.TICKET_ID,
      EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME,COUNT(*) AS NUMBER FROM ACTIVITY
INNER JOIN ENTRY ON ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_ID = ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON ENTRY.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN TICKET ON ENTRY.TICKET_ID = TICKET.TICKET_ID
WHERE ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID = 'RGSTR' 
--added above line since we are checking 
--for tickets that an employe worked >=3 times but couldn't resolve
GROUP BY TICKET.TICKET_ID,EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID) >= 3) c
```

Should I delete the this thread?

Comment: OK, so you have entries that relate EMPLOYEEs, TICKETs, and ACTIVITY/ies. Your example has 6 entries, for two employees (6, 2), two tickets (5, 6), and 1 activity (RGSTR). What do you want to get (expected result) from this sample data? Your question doesn't seem complex, but I fail to see what exactly do you want.

Comment: @TheImpaler  I want to get single number which is cardinality of Tickets that have at least 3 entries by same employee but still the Activity is 'RGSTR'. In a sense I want to get number of tickets where an employee works on the same ticket at least 3 times and can't achieve any progress